# What information is on Georgia birth certificates?

Tags: united-states, georgia-usa

The US state of Georgia restricts access to birth certificates and they are behind a snail-mail pay wall. You can only legally request a birth certificate for yourself and certain close relatives. The only ancestors whose birth certificate you may legally obtain is your own parents.

Registration of birth certificates began in 1919.  If they can’t find the certificate you requested, you still have to pay.

So, before I pay money, (at least $25 as of Jan 2018) fill out a lot of paperwork and wait for a while, exactly what genealogical information can I expect to find on a Georgia birth certificate?

Comment: A link to the site where you can order certificates would be useful -- I'm assuming that's where you got the information in this question.  Upvoted because I think people should learn more about the records they're ordering before they order them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following information is on a 1927 Georgia birth certificate in my posession. Exact fields may vary in other years.

```
County
Town or City
Full Name of Child
Sex of Child
Twin, Triplet or Other
Number in order of birth (for multiple births)
Legitimate (Yes or No)
Date of Birth
Born Alive or Stillborn
Time of Birth
Signature of Physician or midwife
address of Physician or midwife
```

For each of the parents:

```
   Full Name (mother's maiden name)
   Residence (address)
   Color or race
   Age at last birthday (Years)
   Birthplace
   Occupation
```

For the mother:

```
   Number of children born to this mother including present birth
   Number of children of this mother now living
```

You can order Georgia birth certificates for yourself, your spouse, your siblings, your parents, your children or your grandchildren through the [Georgia Department of Public Health.](https://dph.georgia.gov/ways-request-vital-record-0)

Comment: Nice work with this self-answered question! What was your source for the information in your question and answer?

Comment: Excellent -- can you clarify your answer to reflect that you copied the fields from a certificate in your possession? You don't have to say whose it is (and can delete your comment afterward).  As genealogists, it's good practice to cite our sources; I like to encourage people to get into the habit of saying how they know what they know.